# Keep getting "catch without try" error

Tags: java, input, range, limit

I'm trying to limit the user input to a number from 1 to 100,000. I made a try/catch exception but it keeps flagging try and catch saying that one needs the other, when I have them both?

```
System.out.println("Cuenta con abono?");
    String abono = scan.nextLine();

    if (abono.equals("si") || abono.equals("Si"))
    {

    do 
    {
        try {
      System.out.println("Cual es el numero de su abono? ");                //la key para el hashmap que en este caso se asume que el numero de abono es el numero de asiento en el estadio
      Integer numId = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
      if (numId >= 1 && numId <= 100000) {

      }
      else {
          System.out.println("Numero de abono invalido");
          scan.nextLine();
      }
      catch (InputMismatchException error) {
              System.out.println("Trate de nuevo (Debe de ser de uno a cien mil)");
              scan.nextLine();
              } 
        }

      System.out.println("Nombre: ");                   //el valor en si (nombre)
      String nombre = scan.nextLine();

      String oldVal = hm.put(numId, nombre);

        if (oldVal!=null) {
            System.out.println("Numero ID :" + numId + " es "
                    + oldVal + " y ha sido sobreescrito por " + nombre);
        }
                    else {  //este else termina si no tiene abono
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: You're missing a closing curly bracket `}` to close the `try` block, just before the catch.

Comment: Your indentation is screwy, but you seem to have an else between your try and catch, which more than likely is screwing with it since afaik, that's illegal.

Comment: If you use consistent, clear indentation, it'll make it a **lot** easier to avoid making these mistakes in the first place, and spot them when you do.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd bothered properly indenting your code, you'd see:

```
    try {
        ^---#1open
    [..snip..]
  if (numId >= 1 && numId <= 100000) {
                                     ^---#2open

  }
  ^---#2close
  else {
       ^---#3open
      System.out.println("Numero de abono invalido");
      scan.nextLine();
  }
  ^--#3close

  catch (InputMismatchException error) {'
  ^---catch without try, because you're still inside brace #1
```

Comment: Thanks I thought I had ruled out incomplete indents.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing curly braces at:

1. The first `if`
2. The first `else`

And the second closing brace after the `catch` should be at the end of your code block, along a `while` closing loop.